# read zip file with in a java jar file

Tags: java, jar, zip

I have a java application. The executable jar of this application also includes some zip and text file in it, which are read on starting of the application. I can easily deal with reading of the text file using

```
getResourceAsStream
```

, but the issue is with reading of zip file.

I tried to use following code, but that simply increased the memory usage 4 times.

```
      // location of the file
        InputStream is = ChemicalSynonyms.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( strFileName);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(zis);
        String[] wordsArray;

        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            // split on tab and use only the first column
            wordsArray = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().split("\t");
            termSet.add(wordsArray[0]);
        }

        sc.close();
        zis.close();
        is.close();
```

How can efficiently read a zip file, which is with in the same jar file.

**** Edit****
It seems the issues lies at sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().split("\t"); I found couple of forums where they mentioned the splitting can cause consumption of lots of memory.

Comment: How large are the zip files you're procesing?  This process will inflate, and place all "words" into your array in memory.  I'm not sure there is anyway around chewing up memory if you're dealing with a large amount of data.

Comment: Zipped files are relatively small. Total 31MB(after compression)

Comment: I suspect I am not using correct approach of reading zip file using scanner. Is there any better approach?

Comment: You could consider using  a bufferedreader, or bufferedinputstream,, and read out block of bytes (perhaps 8k at a time).  I'm not sure what the end result here is though.

Comment: You're also not using Your ZipEntry at all.... which might be okay if there is only one file in the zip.

Comment: There is only one file in zip file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153396/discussion-between-user1631306-and-slambeth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a zip file, SampleText.zip, located within a java program's jar file, the following code will extract (unzip) the files in the zip file to disk.  I've tested this with 2 files in the zip file. I placed the zip file in the jar file in the package/directory with the class files.

```
package readzipfilefromjar;

import java.lang.Class;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

/**
 * @author Charles
 * 
 * unzips zip file contained in jar 
 */
public class ReadZipFileFromJar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new UnZip()).unzip("SampleText.zip");
    }    
}

class UnZip {

    void unzip(String zipFileNameStr) {

        final int BUFFER = 2048;
        Class myClass = this.getClass();   
        InputStream inStream = myClass.getResourceAsStream(zipFileNameStr);       
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inStream);
        ZipEntry ze; 
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream dest;
            while( (ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
               System.out.println("Extracting: " + ze);
               int count;
               byte data[] = new byte [BUFFER];
               // write the current file to the disk
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ze.getName());
               dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
               while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                   dest.write(data, 0, count);
               }
               dest.flush();
               dest.close();
            }
            zis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tested this, I placed the zip file in the jar file in the package/directory with the class files.

Comment: I will accept your answer. But I found out the cause of my issue. Apprantely, "split" function of java causing some memory leak when its called million times.